# Action perturbation vs Equation of motion perturbation

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, perturbation-theory, approximations

I have a simple question which has been in my mind for some time and I would be thankful if anyone help me to fix it.

Consider the following action :
\begin{equation} 
S=\int\!dt\,({\textstyle\frac12}\dot x^2+{\textstyle\frac12}\dot y^2-x^2y)
\end{equation}
and the equations of motion are  :
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\ddot x+2xy=0,\\
\ddot y +x^2=0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
now I want to perturb the system around the $(\bar x,\bar y)$ which is the solution of equations of motion. Consider the following perturbation :
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
x=\bar x +h\\
y=\bar y
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
The problem is that there are two way to find the equation of motion of $h$ which are not consistent.

**Action Perturbation**

In this way, I plug the ansatz into the action up to second order in $h$ which is :
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
S=S(\bar x,\bar y)+\int\!dt\,({\textstyle\frac12}\dot h^2-h^2\bar y)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
and the equation of motion with respect to the $h$ is :
\begin{equation}
\ddot h+2h\bar y=0,\\
\end{equation}

**Equations of motion Perturbation**

Expanding the equations of motion up to the first order in $h$ gives :
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\ddot h+2h\bar y=0,\\
h\bar x=0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where the second (algebraic) equation is not visible from the perturbation of action.

**My Question**

Which one is the correct description of the perturbation of $h$?

Comment: What does it even mean to perturb the solution away from a solution? You haven't added a new piece to the action yet.

Comment: What happened to terms like $\bar{x}h$ after substituting $x=\bar{x}+h$ into $S$?

Comment: What do you want to find exactly? Your solution $(\bar x,\bar y)$ are _the_ equations of motion for the action $S$. If you perturb the equations of motion they will simply not be solutions anymore. The equation $h\bar x=0$ means $h=0$ which is the only sensible solution. If your perturb the action that will just give different solutions.

Comment: @Sal, Dear Sal, Linear terms of $h$ are vanished by equations of motion (up to some initial terms)

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion, What I want to find is as follows : suppose you have  a physical system which is described by that action ( and the following EOM), and you now want to perturb the system, how do you find the equation of the perturbations?

Answer (score 1):

Your two approaches mean different things, so it's not surprising that they give incompatible results.

If you're perturbing the equation of motion, you are keeping the same dynamical system, which will still obey the same equations of motion, and given some solution to that system, asking "what do nearby OTHER solutions look like?"

If you're  perturbing the action, you are changing which dynamical system you are talking about.  In this case, you are asking, "given this already solved system, with its set of known solutions, if I have this "nearby" dynamical system with slightly different forces, what will the approximate solutions to the nearby system look like?"

Nearly everyone does the second thing, because the first thing is kind of pointless, because, if I've solved the equations of motion, I already know all I need to know about solutions to the equations of motion, and if I haven't solved the equations of motion, what bonus do I get from perturbing around an unknown solution?

Comment: For a general perturbation as $x=\bar x+h_x, y=\bar y +h_y$ both approaches are the same. because the EOM are not decoupled, perturbation of $x$ does affect the response of the $y$ equation, so I guess the perturbation of EOM is the correct description.

Comment: @Arian: you are changing the equations of motion if you are perturbing the action.  it doesn't matter if they're decoupled or not.

Comment: By perturbing the action, Do you mean that I add some term to the action? It is not the question. As I said, in general case, the EOM for the perturbations $(h_x,h_y)$ are the same. I did not change the action.

Comment: @Arian: you've definitely changed the action above, though.  For one thing, the original system is nonlinear and can't be perturbed like that.

Comment: The other thing is, since $x$ and $y$ are coupled, I see no reason to think that you can perturb $x$ while leaving $y$ fixed and still get a solution to your equations of motion.